# TASM : Unnamed variable declaration

Tags: variables, assembly, declaration, tasm

while reading some TASM code I came upon an unknown syntax and I couldn't find what it means :

```
.data
    XX  DW  1
        DB  4
```

What does this mean ? I guess you declare a word called XX initialized to 1, but what about the next line ? Is it a part of the XX declaration or an unnamed variable to reserve some place ?

Comment: If you solved it, post yourself an answer and mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that at the address labelled by XX, I have an access to a word, and then a byte (so 3 bytes are reserved).